# Voto majoritário passo a passo

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como posso calcular o voto majoritário passo a passo, por exemplo, comparando a coluna 1 com a 2, **por linha**, depois a 1,2 e 3, **por linha**, depois a 1, 2,3 e 4, **por linha** e assim sucessivamente.

```
set.seed(1)
a = matrix(sample(1:6, 30, replace = T), ncol = 5)
```

Ou seja, pego a linha `i` comparo todos os elementos, calculo o elemento que aparece mais vezes e retorno o mesmo, sendo como saída uma matriz com `i` linhas e `j-1` colunas .

Comment: Você editou a pergunta mas não deu retorno à resposta do Carlos. Ela não te atende? Se não, por que? Comente na resposta dele para que ele possa adaptar o código, sem dúvida será possível. Seria melhor se você postasse  o output desejado além da explica em texto dele.

Comment: Aprendendo a política ainda, rsrs. Grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma:

```
sapply(2:ncol(a), function(x) apply(a, 1, function(y) names(which.max(table(y[1:x])))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[2,] "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
[3,] "4"  "4"  "4"  "4" 
[4,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "3" 
[5,] "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[6,] "2"  "6"  "6"  "6"
```

A primeira coluna do resultado compara apenas as colunas 1 e 2 da matriz `a` para cada uma das 5 linhas. A segunda coluna do resultado compara as colunas 1, 2 e 3 da matriz `a` para cada das 5 linhas e assim por diante.

Comment: Carlos, editei a pergunta, pois a resposta não foi a esperada. Espero que fixada uma linha os elementos sejam comparados coluna a coluna e retorne a comparação de duas colunas, três etc.

O elemento de saída `b[1,1,]` para essa semente seria, 2 ou 6, o `b[1,2,]` 2 ou 6 ou 5, o `a[1,3,]` 2 ou 6 ou 5 ou 3 e o `a[1,4,]` seria 2. Em seguida o mesmo para as demais linhas de saída.

Espero que tenha entendido e mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Comment: Ok, então você não quer o maior elemento e sim o que aparece mais vezes, editei a resposta .

Comment: Isso mesmo Carlos, mais uma vez muito obrigado. Você tem salvo um mestrado (rsrsrs).

Abraço.